# Is it possible to use websockets with a sports API?

Tags: api, websocket, socket.io, real-time

Is it possible to use web-sockets with an API like below so there free package doesn't give live data therefore could you still use the free package with web-sockets?
https://www.football-data.org/
Thanks

Comment: It is possible IF they provide it. Do they provide it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Hi how would i find out if they provide it? what should i look out for? Thanks

Comment: You could read their documentation and look for "web sockets". Or ask them on twitter or something.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ok thanks ill do that

Comment: Just so you know, "web sockets" is not some kind of magic dust that you can sprinkle over anything and it suddenly becomes a real-time live feed. :) It's a set of relatively complex technologies and service provider must do the work to implement their part.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i was only asking as most free packages say time delay and wanted to know if with those could web-sockets be used or would it need to be a polling technique instead as the paid packages do say live but im not wanting to pay for it

Comment: You probably misinterpret what that "delayed scores" means. The way I see it, they show the score updates only after X minutes since the update happened. If so, no amount of effort on your side is going to have any effect. Polling or sockets, their server is giving you stale data and you can't do anything about that (well, short of paying, that is).